# Can we use any feature of linux in our app?

Tags: android, linux, kernel

Since Android is built on Linux Kernel.Are there any functionality of Linux which we can use in our application?

Comment: better specify what is the functionality you are talking about?

Comment: Hi there

Actually in my app i want to do something Which would prompt user for a security-key of mobile Phone. if users key(key that user types in) matches the key Stored in app the application, then application should finish otherwise user should not be able to do any thing Even close the application(ie system should hang)
And i think this can be done through Linux>>>>>>>

Answer (score 2):

Only that which is exposed as part of the Android SDK or NDK.

Comment: I m not knowing which part of Linux is exposed to Android. Could u help me?

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes as Android is open source therefore you could write wrappers into the system services. But in reality probably not - or at least not worth the effort.

Comment: "In theory yes" What does it mean?
Could u give me let me Know about such theory in Detail?

Comment: This isn't really true.  You could build your own version of Android that makes features available, but standard Android runs third party applications in strong sandboxes that limits what they can do, whether written with native code or not.